# Some issues and difficulties in PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, tabs, android-viewpager

I have implemented a scrollable tab + swipe, everything works fine.
However I have some issues related to the current PagerTabStrip :

**1.** I can't make the current title Bold

**2.** Can't choose the default tab I want to display (e.g : the tab with position 2) when rendering the view, like the tabs in the Google Play app

**3.** The first and last tab have respectively a margin on the left and the right, can I set it to 0dp ?

This is what I could do for styling the tabs :

Java :

```
strip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_tab_strip);
strip.setTabIndicatorColorResource(R.color.light_blue);
strip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
```

Layout :

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_tab_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/pagertitle_border_bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/light_blue" />
```

Can anyone help me with the 3 points ? Thank you.

Comment: did u find a solution?

Comment: @CodePond.org : Actually no, using this widget. The only solution I have found is to create your own Pager : titles scrollable view and swipe content views listener...

Comment: please consider my proposed answer.

Answer (score 11):

Well, I actually found a proper solution for that. Forget about `PagerTabStrip` ;)

Apparently, Google released a [sample app](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html) that features the exact source code they used in Google Play app. It's super easy to use. Download the sample app and copy two files from there: `SlidingTabLayout.java` and `SlidingTabStrip.java`.

Then in your layout XML, add the following above the `ViewPager` (change `com.example` to your package name):

```
<com.example.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

And add the following to the activity after you initialize the `ViewPager`:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new GridPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        // Initialize the SlidingTabLayout. Note that the order is important. First init ViewPager and Adapter and only then init SlidingTabLayout
        mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    }
```

`SlidingTabLayout`'s API allows you to easily do basic styling such as, changing the tab color, the divider color, the indicator color, etc.

One more important thing, the `SlidingTabLayout` that Google provided works well when you have many tabs. But, if you have, for example, three tabs, you'll see that all the tabs are aligned to the left and there's a big gap between the last tab and the width of the view.
[image]

To overcome this, modify `SlidingTabLayout.java` after line 173 just below `TextView textView = new TextView(context);` add the following line:

`textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));`

Now the space among the tabs will be divided correctly:
[image]

Comment: To evenly populate views you can just call its function setDistributeEvenly(true);

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this. This guy explains very clearly how to use Sliding Tab Layout

[Understanding Sliding Tab Layout](http://www.android4devs.com/2015/01/how-to-make-material-design-sliding-tabs.html)

For any customization

Change the code in the class SlidingTabLayout.java